# Continuous $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is convex iff $x \mapsto f(x)+\gamma x+\delta$ does not attain max for all $\gamma,~\delta\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

> Let $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Prove that  $f$ is convex iff for all $\gamma,~\delta\in \mathbb{R}$ function 
>   $x \mapsto f(x)+\gamma x+\delta$ does not attain its maximum value  on $(a,b)$.

**Attempt.** Straight: if for some $\gamma,~\delta\in \mathbb{R}$, convex function $f(x)+\gamma x+\delta$ attains its maximum on $(a,b)$, 
it would be constant (classic result), say $c$. So for all  $x\in (a,b)$:
$$f(x)= -\gamma x+c-\delta$$
and $f$ does not attain its maximum on $(a,b)$, contradiction.

Converse: i have seen graphically that this would be true and maybe we could work with proof by contradiction, but I haven't gotten something so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry if my question is annoying, but are you sure the interval is $(a,b)$ and not $[a,b]$. The statement seems wrong to me for functions that go to positive infinity when $x$ approaches $a$ or $b$.

Comment: Thank you. No, it is $(a,b)$ and the statement seems correct (grafically speaking).

Comment: Augmenting Marwan's comment, consider the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-a} + \frac{1}{x-b}$. Then for any $\gamma$ and $\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we have $f(x) + \gamma x + \delta \to \infty$ as $x \to a^+$, thus it cannot attain the maximum on $(a, b)$. But of course, $f$ is not convex as $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x\to b^-$.

Comment: For a bounded counter-example, consider the W-shaped function $f(x) = |1 - |x||$ on $(-3, 3)$. Then it is obvious from the graph that $f(x)+\gamma x+\delta$ cannot attain the maximum on $(-3, 3)$. Of course, this can be checked by a direct computation. Since $f(x) < 2$ on $(-3, 3)$, for $x\in(-3,3)$ we have $$ f(x)+\gamma x+\delta < 2 + 3|\gamma| + \delta =: m$$ But since $\sup\{f(x):x\in(-3,3)\}=m$, $f$ cannot attain its maximum on $(-3, 3)$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee, true, indeed. And maybe the easiest counterexamples (in both cases). Thanks!